# Direct subdirectory to subdomain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop, http-status-code-302

I want to redirect this: https://example.com/sub-dir/page
to this: https://subdomain.example.com/page

We use prestashop for our main site.  We have some static content in subdictory that we've since moved to a subdomain. Navigating form example.com/sub-dir will direct to sub.example.com with no changes to the htaccess.

The problem is the pages won't redirect.  We get a 404 errors. with example.com/sub-dir/page

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub-dir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.example/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've also tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^sub-dir/(.*)$ https://subdomain.example/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Also this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/sub-dir/$ https://subdomain.example/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on top of your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule . - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^sub\-dir$ sub/ [L]
RewriteRule ^sub\-dir/(.*)$ https://sub-domain.example/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Did not work.  Does it matter that that the subdirectory has a dash 'sub-directory' and the subdomain doesn't?  I'm going to update the question to show what i mean.

Comment: @N13Design You must add a backkslash before dash. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It tried with the backslash before the dash but I'm still getting the 404 error.